# Netsuite Suitetalk API to fetch records from Netsuite using Python

Tags: python, authentication, soap, netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I am trying to fetch the records from Netsuite using the Suitetalk API. While running on postman everything is running perfectly fine but when I am trying through my python script after changing the postman collection to a python code, I am getting the following error. The code and error is as follows respectively:

import requests

url = "https://3342117-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2017_1"

payload = "<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\n  soap-env:Header\n    \n      {account}\n      {consumer-key}\n      {token-id}\n      {nonce}\n      1683708835\n      <signature algorithm="HMAC-SHA256">{signature}\n    \n    \n      \n        false\n      \n    \n    \n      1000\n      false\n    \n  </soap-env:Header>\n  soap-env:Body\n    <get xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\n         xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">\n      <baseRef internalId="4364" type="job" xsi:type="platformCore:RecordRef">\n        platformCore:name/\n      \n    \n  </soap-env:Body>\n</soap-env:Envelope>"
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
'SOAPAction': 'get',
'recordType': 'job'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)

error - **"Invalid Login Attempt"**